# File upload API works in Postman but not React JS

Tags: spring, reactjs, file, upload, postman

I'm currently developing a Java spring boot and React JS application, and am trying to upload files to the server. My spring endpoint looks like this :

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
public UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

My front end code looks like this :

```
let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/api/uploadFile");
    xhr.send(formData);
```

When I submit the request in Postman, with the body selected as form-data, and key of file, everything works and my file is uploaded to the server.

However, when I try the same thing using the front end code, the server says:

```
Required request part 'file' is not present
```

I've tried searching online, and it seems like I'm doing everything correct. I know that my server side code is correct as the request works with Postman.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Is your React App posting `multipart/form-data` as the Content Type?

Comment: Currently I’ve left it blank and the browser fills that in for me. If I add Content-Type : multipart/form-data manually, the server throws the error : “The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found”

Comment: When leaving the Content Type  blank, it gets sent as :

multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydAYzqF71w2OBScGs

I leave this blank in Postman too, and it works.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove headers totally from `XMLHttpRequest` if it presents there, or leave headers as an empty object `{}` without `Content-Type` property.